# time: идентификатор не найден (ctime подрубил)

Tags: c++

Начал учить C++ , написал маленький код .

```
#include <ctime>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int p = rand();
    cout << p <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вылетает ошибка

```
time: идентификатор не найден
```

Comment: #include <time.h>

Comment: пробовал . Не пашит

Comment: @AlexGlebe да не, `#include <ctime>` должно хватать

Comment: в чём проблема может быть ?

Comment: Укажите компилятор/инструментарий

Comment: Visual Studio 17 ; 199711 ; 10

Comment: #include <stdlib.h>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поставьте первым #include "stdafx.h", а все остальные библиотеки подключайте после него.

Comment: это больше напоминает комментарий чем ответ

Comment: @nick_n_a Имхо, вполне нормальный ответ. (Если он окажется правильным.)